# FosUserBundle - Made username nullable true

Tags: symfony, null, entity, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

Commuity,

i use the FosUserBundle and i have a problem with the username.

On my page, you only need a email and a password.
=> you **could** use a username! (because that, i couldnt override the setEmail() function in entity with setUsername($email) ^^

If i use this in my configuration, i get the following error.

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            validation_groups: [AppRegistration]
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null
```

What can i do?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Removing the username might cause complications, so I would recommend you overwrite `setEmail($email)` to also set username in your User-class. This might be redundant, but makes makes sure that each stuff requiring a username still works, e.g. login via username+password. Of course you also have to change the signup form accordingly, so that users don't choose a username other than their email-address, also you might want to change the translation to say email instead of username.

Comment: Hmm okay. I need a field "eusername" which is the correct, optional username and the username "email" ...
Then i must do that. Thanks.

Hope there is another way, too. (maybe in future!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

Change your security.yml to make fosuserbundle accept email as username, from [**Logging by Username or Email**](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md) and make sue you overwrite your setUsername method, because username cannot be empty. E.g.

```
public function setEmail($email){
    parent::setEmail($email);
    parent::setUsername($email);
}
```

Comment: Since mahok's answer i do the same. I added a "subusername" which contains the -> optional <- username ^^

Comment: I want a solution hwo accept empty username and logging by email and username if not empty.

Comment: @khaled_webdev you might want to ask a question on SO then

Answer (score 0):

You can make the username *nullable* by using the **Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverrides** and **Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverride** annotations above the User entity like this:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverrides;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverride;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 *  @AttributeOverrides({
 *     @AttributeOverride(name="username",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name="username",
 *             type="string",
 *             length=255,
 *             unique=false,
 *             nullable=true
 *         )
 *     ),
 *     @AttributeOverride(name="usernameCanonical",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name="usernameCanonical",
 *             type="string",
 *             length=255,
 *             unique=false,
 *             nullable=true
 *         )
 *     )
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
//..
```

This code will make the username nullable in the database **AND not required** in the validation rules.

Source:
https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony-supprimer-username-fosuserbundle